# I have a invisible border in my HTML

Tags: html

I need to do a basic web for my homework without HTML, I have seen many example but I dont undertstand why I have these white spaces.

[image: https://snag.gy/Tg7G26.jpg]

I've tried swapping attributes but...

This is my code.

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
    <table width="100%" style="height: 100%" cellpadding:"10" cellspacing:"0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="white"><h1 align="center"><img src="img/logo.png"></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" height="800px" rowspan="5" valign="top" bgcolor="#d2d8c7"></td>
            <td height="75px"colspan="3" valign="middle" bgcolor="#d2d8c1"</td>
            <td width="12%" height="800px" rowspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#d2d8c7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%" height="20%"   bgcolor="#d1d8c7"></td>
            <td width="40%" height="100%"   bgcolor="#d1d1c7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%" height="20%"   bgcolor="#d1d8c7"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without HTML"? Your HTML syntax is kinda broken, e.g. `cellspacing:"0"` should be `cellspacing="0"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use css by changing the bordercollapse property.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the first line of table. It should be this:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your following line of html

```
<table width="100%" style="height: 100%" cellpadding:"10" cellspacing:"0" border="0">
```

with this:

```
<table style="height:100%; border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; width:100%;">
```